# The [soothing] [school] of [thumb-sucking]

Tags: discussion, tags

Another miscellany of [tags](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags).

---

**1) Soothe**

We have [6 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soothe) tagged [soothe](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soothe).

I suggest to change it to [soothing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soothing), like [swaddling](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swaddling) or [bed-sharing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bed-sharing).

---

**2) School**

- [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school): [177 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school)
- [high-school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school): [2 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school)

I'm a bit surprised to see that [high-school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school) is being used rarely. [26 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school+teen) are tagged [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school) [teen](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teen). I guess that *school* comes more natural to people because this is an international site. Other countries have different school systems and different names. And OPs may not feel the need to be that specific about the type of school.

I also came across [school-selection](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school-selection) with [5 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school-selection). I could imagine its use in principle, but looking at the questions, [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school) should do the job.

---

**3) Thumb-sucking**

We have [7 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thumb-sucking) tagged [thumb-sucking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thumb-sucking) and

[22 questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifier) tagged [pacifier](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifier).

The tag wiki excerpt of [pacifier](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifier):

> Questions about use of pacifiers, dummies, and thumb sucking

We even have two questions tagged [pacifier](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifier) and [thumb-sucking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thumb-sucking)

- [Should I  stop my infant from sucking his thumb?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/2172/30519)
- [When should an infant stop sucking on her hands?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/653/30519)

So either

1. get rid of [thumb-sucking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thumb-sucking) (e. g. make it a synonym of
   [pacifier](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifier)) or
2. change the tage wiki excerpt of [pacifier](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifier).

I'm rather in favor of option 2, since a tag specifically for *thumb sucking* makes sense and was already used several times. I'd rather restrict [pacifier](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifier) to artificial pacifiers.

---

**Q1: Change** [soothe](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soothe) **to** [soothing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soothing)**?**

**Q2: Change** [high-school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school) **to** [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school)**?**

**Q3: Change** [school-selection](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school-selection) **to** [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school)**?**

**Q4: Keep** [thumb-sucking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thumb-sucking) **or change the** [pacifier](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifier) **tag wiki excerpt?**

Comment: You come up with the best titles! :) I agree with all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1: Change** [soothe](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soothe) **to** [soothing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soothing)**?**

I suggest to change it to the -ing form as it's common on Parenting.SE ([search for "ing"](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tags)) and also other stacks.

**Q2: Change** [high-school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school) **to** [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school)**?**

It seems that [high-school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school) never gained traction and so doesn't fulfill its role as a filter for questions. You'll either miss out on the many [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school)-questions (searching for [high-school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school)), the few [high-school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school)-questions (searching for [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school)) or we'd have to add these two tags to questions (note that no more than 5 tags are allowed). Hence I believe we should only use [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school).

**Q3: Change** [school-selection](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school-selection) **to** [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school)**?**

Like [high-school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school) above [school-selection](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school-selection) sounds good in theory, but there are few questions with it and even less where it seems spot on. [school](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school) is just doing fine here.

**Q4: Keep** [thumb-sucking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thumb-sucking) **or change the** [pacifier](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifier) **tag wiki excerpt?**

I suggest to

1. keep [thumb-sucking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thumb-sucking) (enough questions for it to make sense as its own tag)
2. change the [pacifier](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacifier) tag wiki excerpt so it no longer includes *thumb-sucking*.